# Is it possible to change the delay when pressing a key in key event listener?

Tags: java

For example, when I hold down the up key, it runs the code for the left arrow key once, pauses for a bit, then repeats the code. I want to change the time between the first running of the code and when it starts repeating. What should I implement in order to do this?

This is the code that i am currently using:

```java
        JFrame thing=new JFrame();
        thing.setTitle("thing");
        thing.setResizable(false);
        thing.setSize(500,500);

        JPanel panel=(JPanel) thing.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel thing2=new JLabel("thing");
        panel.add(thing2);
        thing2.setBounds(x,y,50,50);
        thing2.setFocusable(true);
        thing2.requestFocusInWindow();
        thing2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    thing2.setLocation(x-10,y);
                    thing2.repaint();
                    x-=10;
                }
             }
        });

        thing.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: When you use `keyPressed`,  you are at the mercy of the operating system to determine the rate and also the initial delay (in Windows go to Control Panel > Keyboard > Speed). Add something at the top of your method which compares the current time to the last executed time, and return early from your method if it's too soon.

Comment: Alternatively, listen for the **first** `keyPressed` event, at which point start an async task with whatever interval you like, and then cancel the task when `keyReleased` occurs.